# KLEMS data variants

Tags: data-request

There seem to be two different sources of US sectoral data from the well-known KLEMs source: one from 1947 and one from 1970. But over a common sample they seem to have different data (even when you difference the series). Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Thanks.

1. The longer one available at:
   http://www.worldklems.net/data.htm from 1947
2. A short one available from 1970:
   http://www.euklems.net/